# Use Static Const Strings To Initialize Arrays and string conjugations

Tags: c++, arrays, static, constants, codeblocks

I have this class

ArabicHarakat.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace sarf{

class ArabicHarakat
{
public:

    static const wstring FATHA ;

    static const wstring DAMMA ;

    static const wstring KASRA ;

    static const wstring SKOON  ;

    static const wstring SHADDA ;

};
}
```

ArabicHarakat.cpp

```
#include "ArabicHarakat.h"

namespace sarf{


    const wstring ArabicHarakat::FATHA = L"ظژ";

    const wstring ArabicHarakat::DAMMA = L"ظڈ";

    const wstring ArabicHarakat::KASRA = L"ظگ";

    const wstring ArabicHarakat::SKOON  = L"ظ’";

    const wstring ArabicHarakat::SHADDA = L"ظ‘";

    }
```

I want to use these constants to to initialize arrays like this

```
wstring ImperativeConjugationDataContainer::emphasizedLastDimList[13] = {L"", L"", ArabicHarakat::FATHA
, ArabicHarakat::KASRA, ArabicHarakat::FATHA, ArabicHarakat::DAMMA, ArabicHarakat::SKOON
, L"", L"", L"", L"", L"", L""};
```

and to conjugate verbs like this

```
inline wstring  AugmentedActivePastVerb::ConjugateInFormula6()
{
    return L"أ‡"+root->getC1()+ArabicHarakat::SKOON+root->getC2()+ArabicHarakat::FATHA+root->getC3()+ArabicHarakat::FATHA+root->getC3()+lastDpa+connectedPronoun;
}
```

but when I compile this code it gives me this error

> undefined reference to `sarf::ArabicHarakat::SKOON
>
> undefined reference to `sarf::ArabicHarakat::KASRA
>
> undefined reference to `sarf::ArabicHarakat::FATHA
>
> undefined reference to `sarf::ArabicHarakat::DAMMA

and so on

I include ArabicHarakat.h in all files that uses it, but it doesn't produce ArabicHarakat.o file in the debug folder

Note: I am using codeblocks on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: You need to compile `ArabicHarakat.cpp` as well as including its header.  Are you doing this?

Comment: yes I am sure ArabicHarakat.cpp is already included in my project

Comment: I had to add the file manually to my project.cbp and it works